# How do I return the sum of all values in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am very new to javascript and am having a problem figuring out if I should use `return` or `document.write` or both to return the sum of all values in an array called 'amount'.  I am supposed to create a function names amountTotal().

The purpose of which is to return the sum of all values in the `amount` array.  Then I am to declare a variable named `total`, setting its initial value to 0. Then create a for loop that loops through all the values in the `amount` array.

At each iteration of the loop, add the current value of the array item to the value of the `total` variable. Finally, after the loop is completed I need to return the value of the `total` variable. The largest array value is `[34]`. This value will be written to a table called `Summary`

This is what I have written so far.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function amountTotal() {
        var total = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < 35; i++) {
            document.write("<td>" + i + "</td>")
        }
    }
</script>
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: At this stage in your learning process, it's safe to just never even consider using `document.write()`. Ever.

Comment: You should use `return` according to me.

Comment: @Pointy I am also beginner to this language. Can you tell me,why not safe? I am asking out of curiosity.

Comment: So the code would read... return[i]?

Comment: if you use return, then call the function from script not from HTML element.

Comment: @ChrisCarter `document.write()` is not really part of JavaScript. It's a browser operation that's really only useful in a few special cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a value from function.

```
function amountTotal(amount) {
        var total = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < amount.length; ++i) {
             total += amount[i]; // add each element in an array to total
        }
        return total;// return sum of elements in array
}
```

Comment: Will do.  Thanks.  Also, a comment about your suggestion.  I failed to indicate that the amountTotal() was to have no parameters.  Will this make a difference? And why use ++i instead of i++?

Comment: `++i` will add 1 **after** the `for` loop instead of before, I guess. The difference in this case ... I don't know.

Comment: @ChrisCarter `++i` is always more preferred over `i++`. `i++ `reads the value of `i` then increments it.

`++i` increments the value of `i` then reads it.In `for` loop it actually doesnt makes a difference.It just a way of coding.But this will surely make a difference if you return `++i` or `i++`.Try returning `++i` and `i++` .Nice question.If you are not passing parameter to function you should declare the variable globally or locally so that yo can access it .

Comment: @DipakIngole, callback is missing from this. `amountTotal(amount);`.

Comment: Please note that he used `amount.length` instead of 35. You should always try to avoid "magic numbers" if you can.

Answer (score 2):

```
function sumArray(arr){
    var total = 0;
    arr.forEach(function(element){
        // 'element' in the parenthesis can be any name
        total += element;
    });
    return total;
}
```